# Is memory segmentation implemented in the latest version of 64-bit Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, memory-management, 64-bit

AMD64 Architecture Programmer's Manual Volume 2 says that most modern system software bypasses the hardware features for memory segmentation, because it is often more efficient to handle memory isolation and relocation with a combination of software and hardware paging support (revision 3.23, page 65, 3rd paragraph). Following, the Manual says that in 64-bit (long) mode some segment registers (system-segment registers) are still used.

This leads me to two questions. Does the latest version of 64-bit Linux kernel:

1) Runs in AMD64's 64-bit (long) mode?

2) Implements memory segmentation? Are these system-segment registers used for anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segmentation is not supported in 64-bit mode. The segment registers still exist for compatibility but do not do anything in 64-bit mode.

It is sad that it took so long for segments do die go away.

Comment: My Professor insists that the memory management of modern operating systems is made with paged segmentation... Only paging is actually used, right?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_segmentation
"The x86-64 architecture does not use segmentation in long mode (64-bit mode). Four of the segment registers: CS, SS, DS, and ES are forced to 0, and the limit to 264. The segment registers FS and GS can still have a nonzero base address. This allows operating systems to use these segments for special purposes."

Comment: Segmentation was an abomination invented to overcome addressing limits of older processors. I assert hat no MODERN operating system ever used segments but rather Intel forced operating systems into using retrograde segmentation. :-)

Comment: I wish I could convince my Professor that she is wrong =(
Thanks for help me clear my conscience!

Comment: In ye olde days of 16-bit processors, it became common to need more than 16-bits worth of memory. Segments came as a solution. In the case of the 8086 kludge on a chip that IBM condemned the industry into using, segments were though to be a means to reduce code size vis-a-vis the much better motorola chips. The segments should have disappeared with 32-bit processing but lived one. Now with 64-bit processors segments have no function. Everything you can do with segments can be done much easier with pages.